# PHP Reference ID auto-increment for invoice

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm looking to create a code that will do auto increment of numbers for use with invoice creation. E.g. 410001, 410002, etc..

i have on my table Clients ->   ID, Reference, Name, Company and Email,

```
<?php

$d = 'A08';
for ($n=0; $n<6; $n++) {
    echo ++$d . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

which outputs:

A09
A10
A11
A12
A13
A14

I'm trying to make If a client has ID=1 or ID=2 on my database, i want to present Reference ID on client side like for ID=1 to be 410001 and for ID=2 to be 410002, so in my table Clients ill have the id and reference id in autoincrement.

Does it makes any sense to you guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these MySQL queries for your table:

Table CREATE query:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (
    ID int(16) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Reference int(16),
    Name varchar(50),
    Company varchar(50),
    Email varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO `CLIENTS` (`Reference`, `Name`, `Company`, `Email`) VALUES (
    (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'CLIENTS' AND table_schema = 'DATABASE_NAME') + 41000),
    'Client_Name',
    'Company_Name',
    'Email'
);
```

Comment: Column ID has 1, Column Reference Should be 410001

Comment: @CarlosSanchez Ah! my bad. I have updated the answer. The `INSERT` query is a little bit complex but should work well. Please have a look.